# Doesn't my bios support booting from USB?

Tags: boot, usb

Seeing that my Ubuntu 12.04 install is quite messed up (refuses to update and random crashes), I want to install the latest and greatest Ubuntu 14.04 on it. Although my machine is still more than fast and large enough for my needs (Quad Core, 6GB RAM and 2TB hard drive) it is also already about 6 years old. I wanted to burn 14.04 on a CD, but my CD drive seems to refuse service (both reading and writing).

I then thought of installing it using a USB stick, but in my BIOS I see no mention of a USB drive (see image below). Does this mean that I cannot boot from USB? So does this mean I have no choice but buying a new CD drive just to install Ubuntu on it?

All tips are welcome!

[image]

Comment: Hard to know from your screen shot. Make a bootable usb, plug it in, and try it. You may have to select a boot device , hit enter, and make an alternate selection. Keep in mind, 14.04 is still in development

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - Thanks for the tip. I just created a bootable USB and kept it in while booting, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to recognise it. I went into the BIOS again, and in the screen which I posted the photo of, it still only shows the CD rom, the floppy and the HDD. It does list the USB stick under hard disks, but those do not seem to be bootable. Any other ideas?

Comment: If your computer can't boot from usb, looking into using the plop bootloader. It's supposed to be bootable even from computers with bios that can't boot usb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **this is the ONLY screen** that is related to the boot order in your BIOS setup, it doesn't seem to support USB boot.

**HOWEVER**, in some BIOS settings I saw before, the `HDD: 4M-SAMSUNG HD1` item in the boot list is actually **alternable**.

Sometimes there is a seperate setup sub-menu in the BIOS setup where you can setup the priorities of all HDDs on the computer and only the HDD with the highest priority in that list appears in the boot menus as an `HDD: ...` item.

Try if you can find such a menu in your BIOS setup and if yes, try if you can find your USB drive in that menu and make it first. After that, the `HDD: 4M-SAMSUNG HD1` item will become something like `HDD: USB...` and then you can boot from it as you boot from an internal HDD.

---

By the way, USB booting should be supported if your PC/BIOS is NOT too old. Even my 8-year-old HP laptop (bought in 2006) supports USB booting without a BIOS upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Boot the USB with GRUB:

- open boot menu
- press `c`
- type `set root=(hd1)` and press Enter
- type `chainloader +1` and press Enter
- type `boot` and press Enter

If this does not work, please post the exact error message.

References: [(1)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromUSB#Booting_via_GRUB) [(2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141381/ubuntu-in-usb-boot-from-fixed-hdd?rq=1)